# Firebase not running JSON script

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have created a script using Android studio. The script log into the app and do some insertion of data and open all fragments.
But when I add the script to my Robo test, it only get to the first screen, then waiting there for 5 minutes and finish with a Passed mark.

Anybody knows anything about this, please help.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and contacted Firebase support.

As per their response, it seems that the delay actions recorded in the Robo script by Android Studio (3.0.1) are extremely long (an hour or more). These long delays block the script execution.

For example the Robo script I recorded starts with this delay action -

```
{
    "eventType": "DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED",
    "timestamp": 1522050751149,
    "actionCode": -1,
    "delayTime": 3596480,
    "canScrollTo": false,
    "elementDescriptors": []
}
```

Notice that the "delayTime" set by Android Studio is 3596480 miliseconds which translates to 59.94 minutes. This value is incorrect.

The quick fix for this is to edit the script manually either by removing the faulty DELAYED_MESSAGE_POSTED events or by editing the "delayTime" values to something more realistic (5000 for example).

Firebase support says that this problem will be fixed in Android Studio 3.2 which is currently in canary.